# Dataweave limit payload number of records

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

How do I limit the number of records in the payload at dataweave level.
For example here I am simply converting to json, but I need only 500 records in the output.

Mycode:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the input is an array, you can use the [slice()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-arrays-functions-slice) function:

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays
output application/json
---
slice(payload, 0, 500)
```

Comment: It's also possible to use the take function from the Arrays module: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-arrays-functions-take